# XSD Yahoo finance

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, yahoo-finance

I would like to use yahoo finance to get stock prices.

The yahoo finance webservice return xml and I would like to get the xsd of this xml to create Java objects whose represent xml.

I don't find the xsd of this table.

So my question is simple: do you know where I can find this xsd (if it exists) ?

Thanks

Comment: You could always start with Java objects and map then to the XML using JAXB's annotations, no XML schema required.  If you need help you can update your question to include sample XML and Java objects representing what you have tried.

Comment: Yes I know I can do that but I would like to generate Java object automatically and not manually (the jaxb's grammar is horrible ;) )

Comment: The JAXB annotations are actually quite easy to use.  Since it is configuration by exception you only need to annotate where the mapping differs from the default behaviour:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have yahoo finance xsd for you

But if your development environment is Windows I can offer a way which it may help you.

I know you are `Java` person and you probably don't like `Microsoft`. In `.net` we have `xsd.exe` tool. (Probably there must be java equivalent for this tool but i do not know about it, so I will explain with `xsd.exe`)

Here you can find the detailed explanation for `xsd.exe` tool

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

with this tool you can generate xsd file from your sample xml. After some small modification in this xsd file you can have compatible `xml schema` with you xml

The key point is in generated xml will define all types in `xs:string` you need to change this types with correct types or you can keep it as it is.

Second important point is generated xml schema can have `maxoccurs="unbounded"`. You need to change this value to `maxoccurs="1"` for non repeating nodes

You can download latest [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) form http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

even if you have older version of this tool you can use it. There is no much change happened since  `xsd.exe` launced